# JavaScript function that sends user to another site

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to make a simple JS function that takes a few of my sites and send the user to a random site once the script activates. I'm using it in two locations one of them is in the navigation php which I include on all sites, and the other is on a hottest.php site.

```
const rng = new Array();
    rng[0] = "http://localhost/joker.php";
    rng[1] = "http://localhost/loophero.php";
    rng[2] = "http://localhost/godofwar.php";
    rng[3] = "http://localhost/friends.php";
function randomlink(){
window.location=randomlinks[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length)]
}
```

I've tried adding onload to the body of a site to test however it does not send to another site once clicked. Don't know it means much but I'm testing my php site on mamp local server.

I use the randomlink in 2 situations on for testing peropuses but neither of them work those are

```
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="hottest.php" onclick="randomlink();"><i class="fas fa-fire"></i></a>
            </li>
```

and

```
  <head>
    <title>DIGIME</title>
    <?php require $meta;?>
    <?php require $css;?>
    <?php require $bootstrapCss; ?>  
    <?php require $script; ?>
  </head>
  <body onload="randomlink();">
    <?php require $navigation ?>
```

The solutions I've found online seem to work for others however they do nothing for me, could this be related to my sites being .php? (Note that other js functions I have work on the sites).

Comment: You might want to debug with the Browser Console (F12 key), where JavaScript errors are shown.

Comment: Getting a Uncaught ReferenceError: randomlink is not defined. However it does infact exist in the JS.

Comment: Seems like at the time of execution of the function, it is not available. You need to investigate how this happens.. Is your JS file actually loaded? `console.log(123)`

Comment: What's `randomlinks` and where is it defined? You define the links in `rng`.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, you are using `randomLinks` in your function, and its undefined.

You have 2 ways to fix your code

> Method 1: Add a parameter to your function

```js
const rng = new Array();
rng[0] = "http://localhost/joker.php";
rng[1] = "http://localhost/loophero.php";
rng[2] = "http://localhost/godofwar.php";
rng[3] = "http://localhost/friends.php";

function randomlink(randomlinks){
    window.location.href = randomlinks[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length)];
}
```

And then you can call your function using `rng` as a parameter: `randomlink(rng)`

> Method 2: Define the links inside the function:

```js
function randomlink(){
    const rng = new Array();
    rng[0] = "http://localhost/joker.php";
    rng[1] = "http://localhost/loophero.php";
    rng[2] = "http://localhost/godofwar.php";
    rng[3] = "http://localhost/friends.php";
    
    window.location.href = rng[Math.floor(Math.random()*rng.length)];
}
```

And then you can call your function without using any parameter: `randomlink()`